# Unable to relink materials as Blender doesn't see them as missing!

Tags: texturing, blend-files

Hi i'm struggling to relink a lost materials in Blender after doing a Save As in another location, whereby losing my references. I originally had linked to the materials and i'm stuck. I cannot remember the folder structure to recreate the path and validate the materials. Another problem is in the Outliner Blender doesn't register them as missing so i am unable to relink them. I have around 200 objects that i need to link to the correct materials.

I have now relinbked manually, but have another 3 blend files (for various LODs - i dont want to put them into the same collection as it spoils the filenames, appending a .001 etc to the end) and was hoping there is a quicker way to reference them, as all objects have the same names across blend files AND are all using the same materials.

So far i haven't found a simple way of selecting multiple objects in the Outliner and applying a material to them in one hit. Any ideas? I'm all ears!

Thanks in advanced.

PS. once i get them linked i will **always** be sure to make paths relative and pack all into .blend file!

[image: BEFORE LINKING OBJECTS TO CORRECT TEXTURES]

[image: AFTER FIXING LINKS]

Comment: Try  [i.filepath for i in bpy.data.images] in the Python console. Not sure of your context, but that can give you folder information.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply... i guess i'm being a bit simple here but i did what you said and it comes up with an invalid syntax error. Not sure how to past a screengrab in a comment :/

Comment: Should work as it is... be sure there is no space before "[" or something like that.